# How does the % count in the "final above-the-fold content" - Prioritize visible content

Tags: amp-html, pagespeed, accelerated-mobile-page

My website has a 3-column design.

I am sticking on Prioritize visible content of google PageSpeed Test

It said "None of the final above-the-fold content could be rendered even with the full HTML response."

Sometime when I edit the code, the msg will change to "xx% of the final....".

How does the % count? And what I have to do to solved this problem?

---

Here is my testing site: https://yudans.net/index2.php

and the PageSpeed Report: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fyudans.net%2Findex2.php&tab=desktop

---

What I did :

- toke off all the render blocking elements,
- put ths css of above-the-fold content in  tag,
- well resized of all imgaes used,
- no external javascript/css used and
- passed AMP HTML
  (validator.ampproject.org/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fyudans.net%2Findex2.php)

What can I do else?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since browsers render things in sequence.  If you have 3 columns, it will have to render the entire 1st column all the way to the bottom to get to the second.  And the entire second column to get to the third.

So you're basically rendering the entire page just to show what's above the fold (visible on page load).

To make **page speed insights** happy, You will want to make it 6 columns. The top 3 columns are above the fold, and the other 3 would be below it.

you can then style them to look like a regular 3 column layout.  BUT, now the html for above the fold gets rendered first, and you can also put just the css for only for the top 3 columns in the head.

[image]

Comment: Before i ask this question, the index2.php was pretty lack of content. 
With all 3 columns was having just one picture(thats means all of them are  above the fold), the error msg is still there. How and why this come out?

Comment: Another question: 
as u can see in my column 1, it is infinite ajax scrolling content, and the height of browser is vary. How can i determine the "line" of the "above the fold"?

Comment: The "prioritize visible content" issue is saying it wants to render only what's 'above the fold' first.  and yes, being above the fold is somewhat arbitrary since monitor sizes/resolutions and window sizes alter what is visible.  The html is rendered from top to bottom.  so they would prefer a layout like: <body><section class='stuff_above_the_fold"></section><section></section class="stuff_below_the_fold"></body>.  so to try and get rid of the error you might need to re-think the page structure (if, of course, you feel the value in fixing it is worth the effort)

Comment: Also, it may not be possible to actually fix that error at this time anyway, it's prevalent, and even sites with pretty much nothing on them, everything inline, no external files.. still get that warning.  I would wager that it is inaccurate, and requires some google dev time to improve.